# App crashes when setting background colour

Tags: java, android

Every time I run my app it crashes giving me a nullpointerexception, I want to programatically change my background depending on the scenario, here is my code:

Main Activity:

```
public class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {


ConstraintLayout layout;

String messageSafe = "Item is Safe for Consumption";
String messageUnSafe = "Item is NOT Safe for Consumption";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_information);


    layout = new ConstraintLayout(this);
    if (matched.length == 0) {
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_safe);
        setContentView(layout);
        changeColor("#00FF00");
        messageView.setText(messageSafe);
    }
    else{
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_unsafe);
        setContentView(layout);
        changeColor("#FF0000");
        messageView.setText(messageUnSafe);
    }


    ListView listContains = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItemsFound);
    ArrayAdapter<String> contains = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foundItems);
    listContains.setAdapter(contains);

    ListView listRestricted = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItemsRestricted);
    ArrayAdapter<String> found = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, matched);
    listRestricted.setAdapter(found);


}
```

Comment: Your `ListView` is `null` (wherever it is defined in your activity).

Comment: post your full xml file and java class

Comment: You have a `null` reference to a `ListView` and are trying to call `setAdapter()` on the object at some point. You need to fix this by initializing the object first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing reference to your old view because you changed the layout to a new `ConstraintLayout` object. This means you now don't have your `ListView` objects and other items in your XML because that View is gone. It's not the ContentView anymore. If you want to work on the existing layout, you need to give the root view an ID.

`<constraintlayout android:id="@+id/container" ... />`

Then you can reference that ID with `findViewById(R.id.container)` and use the object you get from it to change your background like you are doing.

Try this:

1. Give your root view an ID

2. Set a `ConstraintLayout` object with `ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.container)` (Note: You can call it anything, not just container, I am just going off my example from above, since I gave it the ID 'container')

3. call `setBackgroundResource()` like you are doing.

4. No need to call `setContentView()` again, this was set in the beginning, and you do not want to reset it to a new view you just constructed like you were initially doing.

5. You shouldn't crash when trying to call `setAdapter()` to your `ListView` now because you don't have a reference to an object that isn't in your content view.

```
layout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
if (matched.length == 0) {
    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_safe);
    changeColor("#00FF00"); //assuming this is some local function?
    messageView.setText(messageSafe);
}
else{
    layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_unsafe);
    changeColor("#FF0000");
    messageView.setText(messageUnSafe);
}
```

Comment: This worked previously before I had any background images in. Is there any way to work around it?

Comment: As in my code worked perfectly before I had the background, and also I already that that in my code^^

Comment: I see. If you go through the debugger, are you able to make the calls to the `layout.setBackgroundResource()` without issue?

The log you originally posted saying it couldn't start the activity because of the ListView null pointer exception. That lead me to think you had issues with initialization, but I would ask you post more of your code. From here, I don't see the issue without context of where it is happening.

Comment: Ok, the only other thing I can think of is because you used "setContentView(layout) you changed your view. You could likely be trying to use a reference to the `ListView` object somewhere, and that is bad because your old layout is not gone. You created a new one programmatically, so it doesn't exist in that layout, but if you hold a reference still to the old ListView somewhere, it won't work now.

Comment: Just saw the updated code, that is what is happening. You lost reference to your ListView. I'll edit for more info right now.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer, but what should I write in my container.xml? so that my activity would stay intact

Comment: Because currently there is an abundance of listview and textviews

Comment: Also R.id.container shows up as unresolved error even after creating it

Comment: Stay intact in what way? I'm not sure I clearly understand, but remember R.id.container is an example. In your XML for your view, make sure you give an ID to your root view (the constraint layout) via the `<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout    android:id="@+id/[name_here]"` and then whatever is after the `"@+id/` is your id you use for `R.id.[id_name_here]` in `findViewById()`. Make sure this happens after the first setContentView() because the view needs to be set first.

Comment: After you do this, you should have the ability to reach your ConstrainLayout, set it to an object, and be able to modify it the way you intend. It isn't much work, just need to add the `id` to find it and use it, that's all. :)

Comment: So have android:id="@+id/container" in my activity_main.xml? I tried that and it doesnt work...

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the background by replacing the view of your activity (this is what `setContentView()` does). This causes a null pointer exception later because the old layout (defined in the XML) has been replaced, so your list view no longer exists.

Instead, you should get a reference to the *existing* root view (the `ConstraintLayout`, although if you're just setting background you can just reference it as a `View`, no need to be so specific), and set the background on it, like so:

```
findViewById(R.id.container).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unsafe);
```

You'll also need to give the containing layout an id in the existing layout XML:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    ... etc.
```

Comment: Is there a way to just add the background to the existing layout without creating new XML files?

Comment: Yes, absolutely! I am not suggesting adding an XML file, but you need to add an ID for the `ConstraintLayout` in your _existing_ XML file, because it doesn't have one yet, and getting the view you need to modify (the `ConstraintLayout`) is not impossible, but needlessly difficult without it (you can't use `findViewById()`). I used "container" as the ID, you can use anything you like.

Comment: what should I put in my container?

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky Sorry, I used the wrong syntax for the ID: it should be `android:id="@+id/container"`